# Can I destructure a property named after an integer, on an object?

Tags: javascript

Can I destructure a property named after an integer, on an object?

```js
const { 0 } = { ['0']: 'foo' } // doesn't work

// or

const arr = ['foo']
const { 0, length } = arr // doesn't work
```

Comment: MDN also has an example for properties that would be invalid identifiers -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Invalid_JavaScript_identifier_as_a_property_name

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`0` is not a valid identifier (variable name). You'll have to put it into some other variable name instead:

```js
const { 0: containsFoo } = { ['0']: 'foo' };
console.log(containsFoo);
```

```js
const arr = ['foo'];
const { 0: containsFoo, length } = arr;
console.log(containsFoo);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you must supply a name for the property to be destructured into because an integer is not a valid identifier. For example:

```js
const { 0: zero } = { ['0']: 'foo' }
console.log(zero)
```

and,

```js
const arr = ['foo']
const { 0: zero, length } = arr
console.log(zero, length)
```

This is useful for methods like [`String#matchAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll):

```js
const matches = 'foo'.matchAll(/o/gi)
for(let {0: item, index} of matches)
    console.log(item, index)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do `var 0 = "something"` so you won't be able to do that with any kind syntactical variety;